# Angular/TypeScript update element of array of objects

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

please forgive if my question is stupid but I have no idea what am I doing wrong.
I have array of objects

```
export interface IOptionsData {
  option: string;
  optionPrice: number;
  benefit: string;
  benefitPrice: number;
  oneshotPrice: number;
  commitmentPeriod: number;
}

formData: IOptionsData[] = [];
```

And saving data from form in it

```
onOptionChange(i) {
    console.log(i);
    console.log(this.productForm.controls['user_options']);
    this.formData[i].option = this.productForm.controls['user_options'].value[i].option;
    this.formData[i].commitmentPeriod = this.productForm.controls['user_options'].value[i].commitmentPeriod;
    console.log(this.formData);
    ...
  }
```

On first element everything seems normal

My form data:

[image: Form data 1]

And my array data:

[image: Array data 1]

But when I update another item in form, instead of updating that element in array, it updates complete array to that values

[image: Form data 2]

[image: Array data 2]

onChange function is called with correct parameter, there is no multiple functions calls

Have no idea why is this happening

Please if you know any reason why it would

Thank you

EDIT: forgot to mention

Before I went with array of objects, I used individual arrays for each value I need to store.

```
  selectedOptions: string[] = [];
  selectedBenefits: string[] = [];
  selectedPrices: number[] = [];
  benefitPrices: number[] = [];
  oneshotBenefitPrices: number[] = [];
```

And same update worked as intended, only updated value is getting updated

```
this.selectedOptions[i] = this.productForm.controls['user_options'].value[i].option;
```

EDIT No2:

To reproduce this error you don't need html template.

Here is part of .ts file

```
export interface IOptionsData {
  option: string;
  optionPrice: number;
  benefit: string;
  benefitPrice: number;
  oneshotPrice: number;
  commitmentPeriod: number;
}
```

```
demoOptionsData: IOptionsData = { option: null, optionPrice: 0, benefit: null, benefitPrice: 0, oneshotPrice: 0, commitmentPeriod: 24 };
```

```
ngOnInit() {
  /* Initiate the form structure */
    this.formData.push(this.demoOptionsData);
    this.formData.push(this.demoOptionsData);
    this.formData.push(this.demoOptionsData);

    this.formData[1].option = 'TEST';
    console.log(this.formData);
  }
```

[image: Array data 3]

Comment: Add your html so i can regenerate this issue

Comment: It's complicated since this component is only child of another component where is actually used, and it has a lot of code in addition to this, but since it's for company i work for, I'm not able to post it entirely here.
Also all data for form and options to chose (and some other data) are fetched through api from company database, so it would require substantial change to make it work for you

Comment: @AhmedAbdelfattah just figured out you don't need html to reproduce this, added info in original post

Comment: Well, can't really tell with your original problem because we do not have all code, I don't know how your formData is constructed and updated. As for your edit No 2: it is simple, your formData is an array of the SAME REFERENCE demoOptionsData, so, the result is expected.

Comment: @htn So when I push object, it just pushes reference for that object? Didn't know that. That part is similar to my original code, I used variable cause it seemed to me more simple than using { option: null, optionPrice: 0, benefit: null, benefitPrice: 0, oneshotPrice: 0, commitmentPeriod: 24 } every time I push another object in. Removed variable from push and added something like this, now everything works as i wanted. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by comment from @htn
formData is an array of the SAME REFERENCE demoOptionsData, so, the result is expected